# how to start apache-tomcat- 5.0.28 in windows 7 to run servlet Program in java

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, windows-7

I have installed downloaded and extracted apache-tomcat- 5.0.28 in windows 7 Operating system. and then I followed below given instruction.

1. Now Right click on my computer icon, Select properties->Advanced->Environment Variables.
2. Click on new Button in System Variable frame (highlighted in above figure). Clicking on new button open dialog box to add new System variables.
3. Now type CATALINA_HOME in variable name and C:\Program
   Files\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28 in variable value and then click ok.
4. Again click on new Button in System Variable frame
5. Now type JAVA_HOME in variable name and C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_21 in variable value and then click ok.
6. Now select path variable from System Variable frame
   click on edit Button in System Variable frame 
   now add ; C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-5.0.28\lib; and then click ok.
7. Now open Dos prompt by clicking start->run->cmd
   type SET CLASSPATH= C:\Program Files\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\lib\servlet-api.jar
   type cd C:\Program Files\jakarta-tomcat-5.0.28\bin
   type startup (to start tomcat server) and when you need to shutdown server type shutdown

After completing all above step when I type startup in dos prompt I got tons of errors and could not start apache tomcat.
Can any one suggest any solution?

Comment: What errors you see when you try to startup tomcat? PS. Don't post them in comment but update your question using [edit] option under question.

Comment: if you have trouble installing and configuring `Tomcat` you should try an automated installer.

Comment: @Pshemo  can you provide /suggest link for the same,

Comment: #7 is certainly incorrect, but you shouldn't be contemplating Tomcat 5 at all, it was ten years out of date when you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Go through cmd line its easier. cd to the apache-tomcat-5.0.28\bin then type the commands `set JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_21` then hit enter then type`set JRE_home=c:\Program Files\Java\(JRE you have)` your jre will be a file probably next to your Jdk uses its name where the () are. then hit enter type`startup` then hit enter again and it should work.